# angularjs - Update ng-model value from controller?

Tags: angularjs

View 1:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl1">
    <button ng-click="goToExtendedForm({'name':'aaa'})">
    </button>
</div>
```

ctrl1:

```
    $scope.selectedList = {
        name: ""
    };

    $scope.goToForm = function(e) {
        $scope.selectedList.name = e.name;
        $state.go('view2');
        console.log(e); // prints updated value
    };
```

View 2:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl1">

<input
        id="name"
        name="name"
        type="text"
        ng-model="selectedList.name"
        ng-readonly="true"
/>
</div>
```

But the input box is always empty, even though to get to the view the goToForm() is called. Why doesn't it update the HTML value?
Views are changed with ui.router's $state.

Comment: put your code in plunkr.com

Comment: where `goToForm()` defined ?

Comment: Give the entire code, please see how to ask a question on stack.

Comment: without an option to call goToForm(), how you fire goToForm() function ??

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… **Complete** – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: **Ensure that the example actually reproduces the problem!** If you inadvertently fixed the problem while composing the example but didn't test it again, you'd want to know that before asking someone else to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description, your code is supposed to work. Check if you are passing the right parameter into the function. Here is a working demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedList = {
    name: ""
  };

  $scope.goToForm = function(e) {
    $scope.selectedList.name = e.name;
    console.log(e); // prints updated value
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <button ng-click="goToForm({'name':'aaa'})">Change</button>
  <br>
  <input type="text" ng-model="selectedList.name" ng-readonly="true" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `$scope.$apply()` at the end of your `$scope.goToForm` function

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;

HTML Code

```
  <div ng-app>
      <div ng-controller="ClickToEditCtrl">
        <input
                                id="name"
                                name="name"
                                type="text"
                                ng-model="selectedList.name"
                                ng-readonly="true"
                        />
                        <button ng-click="goToForm(testUserDetails)" >Go To</button>

                        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Define controller like this;

```
function ClickToEditCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.selectedList = {
        name: ""
    };
$scope.testUserDetails ={
        name: "nimal"
}
    $scope.goToForm = function(e) {
        $scope.selectedList.name = e.name;
        console.log(e); // prints updated value
    };
}
```